# BOM for Maven plugins

Tags: maven

I'm trying to create a Docker image for Maven that will have the default standard Maven plugins already downloaded.

Is there any Maven BOM that contains or mock pom all the standard maven plugins?

Comment: what do you mean by "standard maven plugins"?

Comment: All org.apache.mavens.plugins

Comment: any maven version has defined all this plugins version already without importing bom

Answer (score 1):

A Maven install is little more than a bootstrap. Most of Maven's functionality is downloaded as a plugin and cached on the first Maven run.

One idea is that you could run the maven command from within the Dockerfile when building your image.

Possibly a more flexible solution would be to run a second Docker container, using Nexus (or similar repo manager) to cache downloaded dependencies:

- [How to dockerize maven project? and how many ways to accomplish it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767264/how-to-dockerize-maven-project-and-how-many-ways-to-accomplish-it/27768965#27768965)