# Maven build, test and run on a docker machine

Tags: java, maven, jar, docker, maven-module

It's probably too soon to ask this question but I hope someone has already had the same problem as me.

I have to build a `jar` that run on a `centos7`, `openjdk-7` machine.

I created a docker machine in a ridiculously short time :) but my issue is more a maven one.

My questions is :

How to generate a jar on remote machine (container powered by kitematic on mac for example :p) with the jdk and environment of this machine ?

Any help we'll be welcome.

--- EDIT

I develop on my mac and I would like to launch the build on a "remote" machine which is, in local, my docker container on the kitematic vm.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? What's to stop you building a Jar in a centos7 container?

Comment: Oh sorry, I completely missing the point : I develop on my mac. I edit the question, thx for pointing this.

Comment: I'm still lost. Are you looking for `docker exec`? Normally you would just do `docker run mycentos mvn command`, probably mapping in a volume to hold the output. Does that help?!

Comment: Nope, sorry it's probably me but The code is somewhere (like on my mac) and the environment and jdk is somewhere else (like in a container). The ultimate goal would be to create an integration process.

Comment: You can mount the code from the Mac into docker container using volumes and use the JDK in the container to compile it. Is that what you're trying to do? It's very hard to understand what you are trying to do and why you think it doesn't work.

Comment: I simply want that I want do a `mvn compile` the code is compiled on the remote machine but not on mine, where I'm coding and the code actually is. I could make a sshfs mount or something like this to host the code in the container but I would like to properly do that.

Comment: What does "to properly do that" mean? You don't need sshfs mount or anything, it should just work out  of the box. I'm lost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dockerize maven project? and how many ways to accomplish it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767264/how-to-dockerize-maven-project-and-how-many-ways-to-accomplish-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just asking how to compile source on your local Mac using a container. If you have boot2docker installed, the following works:

```
$ docker run -v $(pwd)/java_proj:/java_proj java:openjdk-7u65-jdk javac /java_proj/Test.java
```

Assuming you have a folder `java_proj` in your current directory with the file `Test.java`, this will compile the test file and should place the output in the same folder. We can do this as the boot2docker VM shares your home directory and we can then mount the folder as a volume inside the container. The code will be compiled using the compiler and environment of the `java:openjdk-7u65-jdk` image.

Comment: I didn't understand when I first read your answer, but it's totally what I was looking for. The `-v` option is the key. Thank you.