# What is the step by step process to deploy a java app to Docker?

Tags: docker, deployment, jar, dockerfile, devops

I've engineering background mostly with coding/dev't than deployment. We have introduced Microservices recently to our team and I am doing POC on deploying these Microservices to Docker. I made a simple application with maven, Java 8 (not OpenJdk) and jar file is ready to be deployed but I stuck with the exact steps on how to deploy and run/test the application on Docker container.

I've already downloaded Docker on mac and went over this [documentation](https://runnable.com/docker/java/dockerize-your-java-application) but I feel like there are some steps missing in the middle and I got confused.

I appericiate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696439/how-to-build-a-docker-container-for-a-java-app/31710204#31710204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a built JAR file, the quickest way to try it out in docker is to create a Dockerfile which uses the [official OpenJDK base image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/), copies in your JAR and configures Docker to run it when the container starts:

```
FROM openjdk:7
COPY my.jar /my.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/my.jar"]
```

With that Dockerfile in the same location as your JAR file run:

```
docker build -t my-app .
```

Which will create the image, and then to run the app in a container:

```
docker run my-app
```

If you want to integrate Docker in your build pipeline, so the output of each build is a new image, then you can either compile the app inside the image (as in [Mark O'Connor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256618/mark-oconnor) comment above; or build the JAR outside of the image and just use Docker to package it, like in the simple example above.

The advantage of the second approach is a smaller image which just has the app without the source code. The advantage of the first is you can build your image on any machine with Docker - you don't need Java installed to build it.

Comment: I am trying to understand what happens after you run the app ? Does it mean it is running inside docker's operating system ?