# Docker files and build command

Tags: java

I tried to create a container using dockerfile, but I'm not successful.
For loading the application on the docker what files do I need? And what is the build command?

Comment: Provide more details, what is the problem, what is the error ... Please provide all those details.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696439/how-to-build-a-docker-container-for-a-java-application

Answer (score 1):

Docker is a relative new technology and it's quite hard to find suitable documentation for your problem, first of all you will need docker-compose.yaml and Dockerfile, wich are the configuration files. Next you need to access the folder where's your project, and run "docker-compose up --build", for building the project, then "docker-compose down" to stop and "docker-compose up" to start again.

Answer (score 0):

Tanta.
So, basically you'd need the docker installed in your machine, and a **Dockerfile** in your project.

I would indicate this step-by-step for your first example of a docker container:

1. Enter a folder that you can start a new project
2. Execute these command (You will ned **git** ([click here to download it](https://git-scm.com/downloads)) installed):

   `git clone -b v1 https://github.com/docker-training/node-bulletin-board`

   `cd node-bulletin-board/bulletin-board-app`
3. Create a Dockerfile in the current folder
4. Paste this following piece of code in your new Dockerfile:

   > ```
   > FROM node:6.11.5
   >
   > WORKDIR /usr/src/app
   >
   > COPY package.json .
   >
   > RUN npm install    
   >
   > COPY . .
   >
   > CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
   > ```
5. Now you can build and run your all-new container:

   `docker image build -t bulletinboard:1.0 .`

   `docker container run --publish 8000:8080 --detach --name bb bulletinboard:1.0`

So, with these steps, I think you can start to understand how Docker works and how you can introduce this stack in your currently running application.
Please, also check docker-compose docs for reference, it will help you.

Thank you.