# Does Jenkins Pipeline Plug-in support Docker Compose?

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I'm looking for a way to run Docker-enabled build consisting of multiple containers in Jenkins 2.0.

Are there any plans for native support of *Docker Compose* in *Pipeline*, or through CloudBees docker plugins for pipeline.

Or can/must this be addressed by explicit calls `sh docker-compose...`? Maybe even use them inside `try... finally`
to further control services lifecycle.

---

EDIT: The first answer was to suggest a way to build docker containers in jenkins. This is not what is needed here. I (EngineerDollery) want to bring up my target platform in jenkins using compose so that I can deploy my app to it and run end-to-end tests.

Comment: I was able to use docker compose by running a shell scripts, I'm not sure if it can be used in a pipeline but if you can run shell scripts in a pipeline then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I've also finally came with a solution which includes running `docker compose` from `sh` step, embedding it inside `try...finally` clause for lifecycle control. **At this moment there is no support for `docker-compose` from Jenkins plug-ins eco-system**. However I will keep a close eye on an official [CloudBees Docker Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Pipeline+Plugin) and rather experimental [Docker Slaves Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Slaves+Plugin).

Comment: [Docker will be unhappy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653747/using-testcontainers-in-a-jenkins-docker-agent-containers-fail-to-start-norout) if you run Docker compose in a Jenkins pipeline, and your are using Docker Jenkins Agents, and (as is likely) your Docker compose tries to create a Docker bridge network.

Answer (score 18):

After searching in [Jenkins bug tracking](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33753?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20component%20in%20(docker%2C%20docker-build-publish-plugin%2C%20docker-build-step-plugin%2C%20docker-commons-plugin%2C%20docker-custom-build-environment-plugin%2C%20docker-flow-plugin%2C%20docker-plugin%2C%20docker-slaves-plugin%2C%20docker-traceability-plugin%2C%20docker-workflow-plugin%2C%20dockerhub-notification-plugin)%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22compose%22), [JENKINS-35025](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35025) suggests `docker-compose.yml` is taken into account when running a job in a docker container, using a [maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767264/how-to-dockerize-maven-project-and-how-many-ways-to-accomplish-it).

See also [Creating CI pipeline with Jenkins](http://rancher.com/docker-based-build-pipelines-part-1-continuous-integration-and-testing/#Creating_CI_pipeline_with_Jenkins), which assumes docker-compose is installed on your Jenkins server.

Note: a year later (August 2017), [docker-compose is still not supported in the Docker Pipeline plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40878?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20docker-workflow-plugin%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22compose%22)

July 2018, [Ivan Aracki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2884309/ivan-aracki) notes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214628/does-jenkins-pipeline-plug-in-support-docker-compose/38693317#comment89408097_38693317):

> Manually installing `docker-cli` and `docker-compose` with the same version as host's is the solution for now...

Comment: here are the files to run a jenkins container that runs docker inside: https://gist.github.com/aj07mm/9ec82203d45c990e9d8f909109fd8188

Comment: @IvanAracki Not I know of.

Comment: Manually installing docker-cli and docker-compose with the same version as host's is the solution for now... @VonC

Comment: @IvanAracki Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the files to run a jenkins container that runs docker inside:

```
docker run \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --name jenkins \
  getintodevops/jenkins-withdocker:lts
```

reference: https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci

Comment: Interesting. +1

Comment: Can you summarize the step in this answer? Just pointing to an external link (which might go stale one day) is not the best practice here.

Comment: Sure! Just added.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing a similar problem, I found this https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2017/10/03/docker-compose-in-jenkins.html but I do not know what is related to.

My problem is test while developing, and also automate the test in Jenkins, and I am using docker-compose to bring up some php scripts AND a mysql server, to run isolated tests (phpunit as of now).

I could think I can achieve this by

1. creating a network in docker host (with `docker network create`)
2. create and run a mysql docker attached to that network (with `docker run mysql --network=netname --name=mysqlmachine`
3. run scripts by jenkins specifying --network and refering to `mysqlmachine` as host.

But this would means I need to setup db data, cleanup db data, and also leave always on the mysqlmachine even when not needed, consuming some ram resource. I can solve last problem with `docker start mysqlmachine` and `docker stop mysqlmachine` command in my Jenkinsfile defining the pipeline.

But, again, executing a shell into the docker where jenkins is running I can not find `docker` command

For me is a viable solution untill I can not find something better

UPDATE:
I will try the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Slaves+Plugin solution, it has almost what I need

UPDATE 08.02:
as suggest by Alexander Zeitler, using

```
agent {
        docker {
            image 'pdmlab/jenkins-node-docker-agent:6.11.1'
            args '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
        }
    }
```

in Jenkins file allow the use of docker-compose command: docker inside a docker, that is mostly docker near a docker as detailed here: [Docker in Docker - volumes not working: Full of files in 1st level container, empty in 2nd tier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312100/docker-in-docker-volumes-not-working-full-of-files-in-1st-level-container-em)

But I preferred to use another approach, that does not require to run jenkins in a special way.

The pipeline say:

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        sh './build_docker.sh jenkinstests'
    }
}
```

and build_docker.sh does:

```
 jenkinstests)
 docker volume create idealodbconn
 docker run -v idealodbconn:/data --name helper busybox true
 docker cp ./dbconn/db249.json helper:/data
 docker rm helper

 docker-compose -f services/docker-compose-jenkins.yml up \
 --abort-on-container-exit \
 --exit-code-from idealoifapi

 docker-compose -f services/docker-compose-jenkins.yml rm -f
 docker volume rm idealodbconn
 ;;
```

Also here `--abort-on-container-exit` say to exit once one container defined into docker-compose-jenkins.yml exits, and `--exit-code-from idealoifapi` says to take exit code from idealoifapi image.

That is all. Missing part, maybe, is the docker-compose-jenkins.yml use of volume, it is external: true:

```
volumes:
    idealodbconn:
        external: true
```

Comment: Really I still have to test it, pm and customer demands changed task priorities, I was coming back to this 2 days ago, but again I am in another task now. I will know it. But it looks complex, because I need to define a Dockerfile to build, and normally jenkins pipeline expect a Dockerfile (or image) to build from. So I think I should first move code and files (also the jenkins pipeline file) into the container built by Docker Slave and then execute pipeline there with the support of side container.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't look like the plugin does install `docker-compose`. I solved it  creating an image containing Node.js, Docker and Docker Compose. This image is referenced in `agent` in `Jenkinsfile`. Due to Docker in Docker Volume Mappings don't work as expected but the solution is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312100/docker-in-docker-volumes-not-working-full-of-files-in-1st-level-container-em
This is the Dockerfile: https://github.com/PDMLab/jenkins-node-docker-agent

Comment: on volume mounting I do not like the undestand-by-misunderstood approach like that. Instead I create a symbolic volume, copy file into it, run the tests, then remove the volume as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468788/what-is-the-right-way-to-add-data-to-an-existing-named-volume-in-docker
this solution does not require a special setup of jenkins, it is all managed by the docker api, communicating via socket, so it is more general. I update the answer with details

Answer (score 2):

I got `docker-compose` working in Jenkins pipelines using [Nestybox](https://www.nestybox.com/), as described in their [blog post](https://blog.nestybox.com/2019/09/29/jenkins.html). I built my Jenkins installation itself using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM nestybox/jenkins-syscont:latest
# Install docker-compose
RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \ 
&& chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

With that I simply followed the instructions in the [blog post](https://blog.nestybox.com/2019/09/29/jenkins.html) and can run pipelines that look something like this:

```
pipeline {

   agent any

   stages {
       stage('docker-compose') {
           steps {
              sh "docker-compose build"
              sh "docker-compose up -d"
              ...
           }
       }
   }
   post {
      always {
         sh "docker-compose down || true"
      }
   }   
}
```

Comment: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?