# Docker in Docker - volumes not working: Full of files in 1st level container, empty in 2nd tier

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, docker-volume, docker-in-docker

I am running Docker in Docker (specifically to run Jenkins which then runs Docker builder containers to build a project images and then runs these and then the test containers).

This is how the jenkins image is built and started:

```
docker build --tag bb/ci-jenkins .
mkdir $PWD/volumes/
docker run -d --network=host  \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \
  -v $PWD/volumes/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
  --name ci-jenkins bb/ci-jenkins
```

Jenkins works fine. But then there is a `Jenkinsfile` based job, which runs this:

```
docker run -i --rm -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/forkMV_jenkins-VOLTRON-3057-KQXKVJNXOU4DGSUG3P27IR3QEDHJ6K7HPDEZYN7W6HCOTCH3QO3Q:/tmp/build collab/collab-services-api-mvn-builder:2a074614 mvn -B -T 2C install
```

And this ends up with an error:

> The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/tmp/build).

When I do `docker exec -it sh` to the container, the `/tmp/build` is empty. But when I am in the Jenkins container, the path `/var/jenkins_home/...QO3Q/` exists and it contains the workspace with all the files checked out and prepared.

So I wonder - **how can Docker happily mount the volume and then it's empty?***

What's even more confusing, this setup works for my colleague on Mac.
I am on Linux, Ubuntu 17.10, Docker latest.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After some research, calming down and thinking, I realized that Docker-in-Docker is not **really** so much "-in-", as it is rather "Docker-next-to-Docker".

The trick to make a container able to run another container is sharing `/var/run/docker.sock` through a volume: `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

And then the `docker` client in the container actually calls Docker on the host.

The volume source path (left of `:`) does not refer to the middle container, but to the host filesystem!

After realizing that, the fix is to make the paths to the Jenkins `workspace` directory the same in the host filesystem and the Jenkins (middle) container:

```
docker run -d --network=host  \
   ...
   -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
```

And voilá! It works.  (I created a symlink instead of moving it, seems to work too.)

It is a bit complicated if you're looking at colleague's Mac, because Docker is implemented a bit differently there - it is running in an Alpine Linux based VM but pretending not to. (Not 100 % sure about that.) On Windows, I read that the paths have another layer of abstraction - mapping from `C:/somewhere/...` to a Linux-like path.

I hope I'll save someone hours of figuring out :)

Comment: "_The volume source path (left of `:`) does not refer to the middle container, but to the host filesystem!_"

This was the epiphany for me!

Comment: For windows I had to use my full path in the format `/c/Users/...`, weird to have windows paths but linux separators.

Comment: there is a more detailed explanation about a similar problem with GitLab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/41227#note_52029664

Answer (score 4):

## Alternative Solution with Docker cp

I was facing the same problem of mounting volumes from a Build that runs in a Docker Container running in a Jenkins server in Kubernetes. As we use `docker-in-docker`, `dind`, I couldn't mount the volume in either ways proposed here. I'm still not sure what the reason is, but I found an alternative way: use `docker cp` to copy the build artifacts.

[image]

## Multi-stage Docker Image for Tests

I'm using the following Dockerfile stage for Unit + Integration tests.

```
#
# Build stage to for building the Jar
#
FROM maven:3.2.5-jdk-8 as builder
MAINTAINER marcello.desales@gmail.com

# Only copy the necessary to pull only the dependencies from registry
ADD ./pom.xml /opt/build/pom.xml
# As some entries in pom.xml refers to the settings, let's keep it same
ADD ./settings.xml /opt/build/settings.xml

WORKDIR  /opt/build/

# Prepare by downloading dependencies
RUN mvn -s settings.xml -B -e -C -T 1C org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:go-offline

# Run the full packaging after copying the source
ADD ./src /opt/build/src
RUN mvn -s settings.xml install -P embedded -Dmaven.test.skip=true -B -e -o -T 1C verify

# Building only this stage can be done with the --target builder switch
# 1. Build: docker build -t config-builder --target builder .
# When running this first stage image, just verify the unit tests
# Overriden them by removing the "!" for integration tests
# 2. docker run --rm -ti config-builder mvn -s settings.xml -Dtest="*IT,*IntegrationTest" test
CMD mvn -s settings.xml -Dtest="!*IT,!*IntegrationTest" -P jacoco test
```

## Jenkins Pipeline For tests

- My Jenkins pipeline has a stage for running parallel tests (Unit + Integration).
- What I do is to build the Test Image in a stage, and run the tests in parallel.
- I use `docker cp` to copy the build artifacts from inside the test docker container that can be started after running the tests in a named container.

  - Alternatively, you can use Jenkins stash to carry the test results to a `Post` stage

At this point, I solved the problem with a `docker run --name test:SHA` and then I use `docker start test:SHA` and then `docker cp test:SHA:/path .`, where `.` is the current workspace directory, which is similar to what we need with a docker volume mounted to the current directory.

```
stage('Build Test Image') {
  steps {
    script {
      currentBuild.displayName = "Test Image"
      currentBuild.description = "Building the docker image for running the test cases"
    }
    echo "Building docker image for tests from build stage ${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
    sh "docker build -t tests:${env.GIT_COMMIT} -f ${paas.build.docker.dockerfile.runtime} --target builder ."
  }
}

stage('Tests Execution') {
  parallel {
    stage('Execute Unit Tests') {
      steps {
        script {
          currentBuild.displayName = "Unit Tests"
          currentBuild.description = "Running the unit tests cases"
        }
        sh "docker run --name tests-${env.GIT_COMMIT} tests:${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
        sh "docker start tests-${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
        sh "docker cp tests-${env.GIT_COMMIT}:/opt/build/target ."

        // https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#advanced-scripted-pipeline#using-multiple-agents
        stash includes: '**/target/*', name: 'build'
      }
    }
    stage('Execute Integration Tests') {
      when {
        expression { paas.integrationEnabled == true }
      }
      steps {
        script {
          currentBuild.displayName = "Integration Tests"
          currentBuild.description = "Running the Integration tests cases"
        }
        sh "docker run --rm tests:${env.GIT_COMMIT} mvn -s settings.xml -Dtest=\"*IT,*IntegrationTest\" -P jacoco test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A better approach is to use [Jenkins Docker plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) and let it do all the mountings for you and just add `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` in its `inside` function arguments.

E.g.

```
docker.build("bb/ci-jenkins")
docker.image("bb/ci-jenkins").inside('-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock')

{
 ...
}
```