# Jenkins in Docker: clarification about bind mounts in pipelines

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-volume, mounted-volumes

I'm running Jenkins in a Docker container. Following this [article](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/), I'm bind mounting the Docker socket in order to interact with it from the dockerized Jenkins. I'm also bind mounting the container directory `jenkins_home`. Here is a quick recap on my volumes:

```
# Jenkins
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
  - /usr/local/bin/docker-compose:/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - ./bar:/var/jenkins_home
```

I run this from the directory `/home/foo/` of the host, therefore the following directory is created in the host file system (and mounted):

```
/home/foo/bar
```

Now, I have a Jenkins pipeline (`mypipe`) that runs a docker-compose file spinning up a MySQL container with the following volume:

```
# MySQL created from Jenkins
volumes:
  - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Weirdly enough, it ends up mounting:

`/var/jenkins_home/workspace/mypipe/data` < `/var/lib/mysql`

instead of:

`/home/foo/bar/workspace/mypipe/data` < `/var/lib/mysql`

Here is a graphical recap:

[image]

Searching stackoverflow, [it turned out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49312179/4820341) that it happens since:

> The volume source path (left of :) does not refer to the middle container, but to the host filesystem!

And that's ok, but my question is:

### Why there?

I mean why does `.data` is *translated* exactly into the path: `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/…/data`, since the MySQL container is not aware of the path `/var/jenkins_home`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Docker creates a bind mount, it is always from an absolute path in the host filesystem to an absolute path in the container filesystem.

When your `docker-compose.yml` names a relative path, Compose first expands that path before handing it off to the Docker daemon.  In your example, you're trying to bind-mount `./bar` from a file `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/mypipe/docker-compose.yml`, so Compose fills in the absolute path you see when it invokes the Docker API.  Compose has no idea that the current directory is actually a bind-mount from a different path in the Docker daemon's context.

If you look in the Jenkins logs at what scripted pipeline invocations like `docker.inside { ... }` do, mounts the workspace directory to an identical path inside the container it launches.  Probably the easiest way to work around the mapping problem you're having is to use an identical `/var/jenkins_home` path on the host system, so the filesystem path is the same in every context.

Comment: Yes, the workaround you mentioned works fine. I was just curios about the reason why the MySQL container was aware of the path `/var/jenkins_home` and, as you explained, it is due to bind-mount dynamics. Thanks!