# Selenium Grid Docker-Compose automation through Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I am using docker-compose for selenium grid automation for firefox and chrome browsers, on an ubuntu 16.04 server and am accessing using PuTTY terminal.

It is a maven project on a git repository. For Jenkins, I have another server instance (accessible via PuTTY).

Questions:

1) How can I build a Jenkins job which will run automatically at a particular time everyday?

2) Is it possible to provide the suite file (testng.xml) path and any maven command to instigate it via anyway?

3) Do I have to manually start grid or can I configure it manually in docker-compose.yml file?

PS: This is my first time so, any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See [How do I schedule jobs in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-do-i-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins)
2. Yes, via String parameter supplied to your jenkins job. 
   you will need to pass it as an argument, for example to invoke maven build the String param value would be:

   `mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml test`

and the shell command:

```
 sh """ '${params.MVN_STRING}' """
```

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

3. See this answer: [Does Jenkins Pipeline Plug-in support Docker Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214628/does-jenkins-pipeline-plug-in-support-docker-compose)

Comment: thanks for the info. Our team has decided to skip with the Jenkins Pipeline issue for now. But anyways, great help. Thanks.