# Adding Maven build steps into docker file for Java Jar?

Tags: java, docker, maven, jar, jboss

I have a `Java` project that builds a `jar` file that is then ran on a `Jboss EAP` server. The `jar` file is built using the maven command:

```
mvn clean install
```

Currently I am building the `jar` manually using `maven` then adding it to my `dockerfile` as follows:

```
# rest of dockerfile...

EXPOSE 8080 9990
ADD app.jar "/opt/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/"

RUN ["chmod", "+rx", "/opt/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/"]
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/opt/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/standalone.sh"]
```

How can I add the `maven` command into my `dockerfile` so that a developer *does not* need to install maven and build it themselves first?

i.e. the steps will just be:

```
1. checkout the code from git
2. run dockerfile
```

I think the best approach is to use a [multi stage build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767264/how-to-dockerize-maven-project-and-how-many-ways-to-accomplish-it) similar to what is suggested here? However I am not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dockerfile examples in [Mark O'Connor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27768965/14030788) to the question you've linked to should be very close to what you need. Those are [multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) because they have multiple `FROM`s in them. The first stage uses a base image that already contains maven, so no need to install it: `FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build`.

Your current Dockerfile content then becomes the second stage, but you will need to replace your `ADD app.jar ...` with a `COPY` which picks the file out of the `build` stage. Something like

```
COPY --from=build /path/to/mvn/output/app.jar \
        /opt/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/
```

The `--from=build` refers to the `AS build` from the earlier stage. No other files from the build stage will be copied into the later stage(s), so the final image will consist only of layers from the last `FROM` onwards.

Editing to add: To address the question of how this prevents another user from needing to do any build and install manually: A new user can do this, instead. Assuming that Dockerfile lives in the root of your git project.

```
git clone <url> your-app
docker build -t your-img your-app # builds all stages
docker run --rm -it your-img      # runs whatever the final stage produced
```

Comment: This has been very useful, but I am quite confused as my java project is multi module, therefore I cannot just copy src?

Answer (score 0):

You can say to do all that in a Dockerfile! You can provide instructions to install maven inside Dockerfile first and then run whatever command you need from the installed maven.

For instance,

```
RUN cd /usr/local && wget -O- http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/rsync.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz | tar -xzf -
```

to install maven 3.6.3 and then later run a command that does what you need whether it be maven clean or whatever.

I just provided the above command because I had it lying around, but if the version you want is available in yum, the other way would just be to use whatever package manager is installed. Like `RUN yum --assumeyes install ________`.

You should be able to do something similar with Git. I would read about best practices surrounding that.