# How to add JavaFX library to docker image

Tags: java, docker

I'm using Yellowfin 9.6 and want to use ability to export both Dashboards and Present to PDF. In https://community.yellowfinbi.com/knowledge-base/article/yellowfin-9-3-and-exporting-dashboardspresent-to-pdf one of the requirements is JavaFX. Found a guide to add JavaFX to system https://community.yellowfinbi.com/topic/how-do-i-add-javafx-to-my-system but not in docker image. How can I add it?

Comment: depending on your base image (OS/platform), follow the steps 2.-4. of the ["how do I article"](https://community.yellowfinbi.com/topic/how-do-i-add-javafx-to-my-system) (doing them in your container, if you have a linux based system(`[sudo] apt-get install openjfx`), you can skip step 3.(unzip) , for step 4. just `add`/`copy` the according file, step 5. should be somewhere "at the end" of your dockerfile)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes using a linux based system. Instead of apt-get install openjfx can I use maven repo to get the jar files or zip file and copy to the image?

Comment: rather comment, but welcome! :-) "Instead of apt-get install openjfx can I use maven repo to get the jar files or zip file and copy to the image?" - Sorry, that I don't /you have to know/test ...but this is the question "whether installing openjfx is needed" (for your app to run ..or the maven deps are sufficient). But generally, you can be sure: when maven runs (without "issues") inside a container, the dependencies will be there! (in the container) ..have you also seen [theirs](https://hub.docker.com/u/yellowfinbi)  ..or [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/rburgst/java8-openjfx-docker)?

Comment: Yes comment ofc :-) Yes have seen the official Yellowfin image.  I think It already comes bundled with a Java version that supports JavaFX, but I'm using a custom image. So I have to copy/install the files

Comment: "If you want to develop JavaFX applications using Maven, you don't have to download the JavaFX SDK" !;) source: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Comment: once running locally/in "dev environment", here are nice answers (with [tag:spring-boot] & without) on ["How to dockerize maven project? and how many ways to accomplish it?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27767264/592355)