# Why does my backend fail to access to the SQL server when I do a multi-stage builds on Docker?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have a backend that runs on Spring and I had to create a Docker container.

To do this, I created a `.jar` file using Maven by running this `mvn package` then I did the `docker run build` command to create my container.

Here is the first content of my DockerFile.

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
COPY target/dwh_webservices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 443
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

I want to point out that my Container is perfectly functional with this first method.

However, it's a pain to have to run the command every time. Moreover, I would like to make pipelines and automate the creation of the `.JAR` with Maven. So I decided to integrate the creation of the `.JAR` in the Dockerfile.

For that, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767264/how-to-dockerize-maven-project-and-how-many-ways-to-accomplish-it) question that explains the Multi-stage and I created this Dockerfile :

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 as build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/dwh_webservices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/app.jar
EXPOSE 443
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

And when I run it, I have this error that appears:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host BACKENDSERV, port 1433 has failed. Error: "BACKENDSERV Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.
```

Since it's the exact same source code plus the fact that the first `.jar` is working, then it should also work. Why, when using the second method, does the application fail to access the host?

What causes this change?

Comment: It seems like there's some sort of bug in your build process where it's incorrectly depending on an external database to produce a `.jar` file.  You can't access other services from within a Dockerfile, and getting a different `.jar` depending on the contents of one specific database seems like it's not going to get reproducible results.

Comment: @DavidMaze do you know any alternative to help me? I didn't find any.